# Can I install Angular Material library without Bower or NPM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, bower

I want to install the Angular Material library in a project, but I am behind a corporate firewall and even configuring the proxy doesn't work, it seems the proxy blocks certain types of files. Is there a way to install this offline?

FYI this is my BundleConfig

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
                      "~/Scripts/angular-loading/loading-bar.css",
                      "~/Scripts/nya-bs-select/nya-bs-select.min.css",
                      "~/Content/angular-ui-switch.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular")
                .Include("~/Scripts/angular.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js",
                    "~/Scripts/AngularApp/app.js")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/app", "*.js", true)
                .Include("~/Scripts/smart-table/smart-table.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-loading/loading-bar.js",
                "~/Scripts/nya-bs-select/nya-bs-select.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/moment.js"));
```

Comment: Just go to the angular website and download angular and include it into your project

Comment: Can you use the CDN instead? https://github.com/angular/material#cdn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the CDN link in your reference, as explained in the [docs](https://github.com/angular/material#cdn), or download the source from CDN.

excerpt from the docs:

```
<head>

    <!-- Angular Material CSS using GitCDN to load directly from `bower-material/master` -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Javascript using GitCDN to load directly from `bower-material/master` -->
    <script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>

</body>
```

Or grab the [Source](https://cdn.gitcdn.xyz/cdn/angular/bower-material/7ba8052aaa334aa0912ae4ba1f2bf34485c473a1/angular-material.js)

Comment: I tried the CDN link but for some reason was getting JS errors. I'm fairly new to angular so getting dependencies is still giving me difficulties. If I just want to include the JS files in my project, do I need all 4 .js files you mentioned above and the .css file downloaded in my local project?

Comment: Just added my bundleconfigs above. Do I download the 5 above files, put them in my project and then add them to the CSS and JS bundles.add(...) lines above?

Comment: @NZJames: You *can* do that, or just copy the lines as they are. It depends on whether or not you want to bundle them. You can create a new bundle as well if you'd like, there's no requirement to do it.

Comment: I'm still not understanding. What link would I use to download `angular-material.min.js` for version 1.1.3?

Comment: @GarretWilson Today it's probably easier to use yarn or npm to download everything and then use a bundler when you publish your site.

Comment: @Patrick Perhaps. Or perhaps not. Maybe it doesn't work with the JAR-based configuration we're using. Or maybe we haven't had time to migrate to that. Whatever the case, without detracting from your advice, it remains that they should simply provide a link for those who need to download a certain version.

Answer (score 0):

download from [here](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.js), save of your pc and include in your project ?

Answer (score 0):

It's really confusing; I don't know why they can't put a freakin' Zip archive on GitHub like everyone else that contains all the dependencies. (They include a Zip file, but without the distribution minified files.)

By looking at the source code of the [Angular Material site](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/), it seems you can use the following links to get the latest files:

- https://material.angularjs.org/latest/angular-material.min.js
- https://material.angularjs.org/latest/angular-material.min.css